# Java RSA Public Key from String Error

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public

I'm trying to convert a string to RSA public key, but I always get errors...
Public Key:

```
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1OzdsHD2yN2USnmgTplY
otoh974+mQ9nw9T3UmxCossD9WjdPJ7UbHXeMVgFrY53x9YfPFmuA5/YNs1eXzSq
Y+GdJIrbdQCHDzWLzNv0mbbAvvv7s706F5HoAPMgjBYV7vZDbiIinupxpx5rns4u
AYJTWOyByCoSsJ9ucVg3kxl3dYrRk9VXH3dHar8CiypvDJPnBCS58xXgh12dPJES
35kvtkDmDsMoBcol3PIK7a8HaMQYmYsAPF+TzhURaUAcVJu/jhOUaDf/4w28JdaW
xykTaDqOZD72RYb1rovK3uFEfgKBJgaAFhPlY2/4m/eNW/SLfwSCR9FvHc88fYpJ
bwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The code:

```
pub.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        byte[] publicByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pub);
        System.out.println(publicByte.length+"deb");

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicByte);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PublicKey pkey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d
```

I would be happy for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x2d is `-`. The hyphens etc. are still there.  `String.replace()` *returns* the new value. It doesn't mutate the string you called it on.